# Scraping html table and its href Links in R

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest

I am trying to download a table that contains text and links. I can successfully download the table with the link text "Pass". However, instead of the text, I would like to capture the actual href URL.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(stringr)

link <- "http://www.qimedical.com/resources/method-suitability/"

qi_webpage <- read_html(link)

qi_table <- html_nodes(qi_webpage, 'table')
qi <- html_table(qi_table, header = TRUE)[[1]]
qi <- qi[,-1]
```

Above gives a nice dataframe. However the last column only contains the text "Pass" when I would like to have the link associated with it. I have tried to use the following to add the links, but they do not correspond to the correct 
row:

```
qi_get <- GET("http://www.qimedical.com/resources/method-suitability/")
qi_html <- htmlParse(content(qi_get, as="text"))

qi.urls <- xpathSApply(qi_html, "//*/td[7]/a", xmlAttrs, "href")
qi.urls <- qi.urls[1,]

qi <- mutate(qi, "MSTLink" = (ifelse(qi$`Study Protocol(click to download certification)` == "Pass", (t(qi.urls)), "")))
```

I know little about html, css, etc, so I am not sure what I am missing to accomplish this properly.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for `a` elements inside of table cells, `td`. Then you want the value of the `href` *attribute*. So here's one way, which will return a vector with all the URLs for the PDF downloads:

```
qi_webpage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run your code by itself, it gives them in the same order as in the table. However, when I plug your code into my mutate, it again puts them in the wrong order.

Comment: `qi <- mutate(qi, "MSTLink" = (ifelse(qi$`Study Protocol(click to download certification)` == "Pass", (qi_webpage %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a") %>% html_attr("href")), "")))`

Comment: Maybe mutate is not the way to go? If you can scrape the table and get the same number of rows as the vector of PDFs, you could just add the vector as a new column.