# Scraping html table and its href Links in R when there are more than one table and particularities

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, href

My question is actually the same as the one asked here : [Scraping html table and its href Links in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926349/scraping-html-table-and-its-href-links-in-r)

But the solution provided does not work in my case...or there is something I didn't understand...
In my case, the webpage has more than a table and I don't know how to target a specific table with the solution provided in the other question...

For example in this webpage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Champions_League, how would I focus on the table "All time top scorers"? How would I get the links for the columns "Player","Country" and "Club(s)"?

I tried something like

```
links = read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Champions_League") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[5]')%>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//td/a')%>% html_attr("href")
```

But it keeps giving me other links.

Besides, there is another difficulty that some names are in bold here and some are not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download all the tables present in the page and select the one which you need.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Champions_League'
all_tables <- url %>%
               read_html() %>%
               html_nodes('table.wikitable') %>%
               html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

So in your case, you need

```
all_tables[[4]]

#                  Player     Country Goals Apps Ratio     Years ....
#1  1   Cristiano Ronaldo    Portugal   128  168  0.76     2003– ....
#2  2        Lionel Messi   Argentina   114  140  0.81     2005– ....
#3  3                Raúl       Spain    71  142  0.50 1995–2011 ....
#4  4       Karim Benzema      France    64  118  0.54     2006– ....
#5  5  Robert Lewandowski      Poland    63   85  0.74     2011– ....
#6  6 Ruud van Nistelrooy Netherlands    56   73  0.77 1998–2009 ....
#7  7       Thierry Henry      France    50  112  0.45 1997–2010 ....
#8  8  Alfredo Di Stéfano   Argentina    49   58  0.84 1955–1964 ....
#9  9   Andriy Shevchenko     Ukraine    48  100  0.48 1994–2012 ....
#10 9  Zlatan Ibrahimović      Sweden    48  120  0.40 2001–2017 ....
```

You might also be interested in [`WikipediR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WikipediR/WikipediR.pdf) package which helps to retrieve data from Wikipedia.

---

To get the `href` links from that table we can do

```
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('table.wikitable') %>%
  .[[4]] %>%
  html_nodes('a') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org', .)

#[1] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo"       
#[2] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugal"                
#[3] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_United_F.C." 
#....
```

Comment: Not really, I already had that. What I am trying to do is to extract the links associated. For exemple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristiano_Ronaldo , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi , etc...

Comment: @K.Hua Updated the answer. Is that what you need ?

Comment: Yes, thanks ! Any way to focus on a specific column of the table?

Comment: There could be but I cannot think of an easy way to do that now. If you get the data in a table select a specific column you loose the `href` information from it.